# Dataset fill RichTextBox

Tags: c#

I'm not sure how the Dataset queries work, so far I can only fill an existing table with the code:

```
tableNameTableAdapter.someQueryName(DataSet.members, @variables);
```

I wonder how I can run this query and save the results into a string instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than using a dataset, look into using a `SqlCommand`.

Or to make your life even easier, look into `Entity Framework` or `nhibernate`.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend LINQ to SQL. It's deprecated in favor of EF.

Comment: This is the way I've learned in a study book, is this the wrong way?

Comment: @user2480500 it's a way to fill a dataset, not the right way to return a scalar value.

Comment: I don't understand. Is this the beginners way of doing SQL? I'm used to PHP SQL, I think it'd be alot eaier if I were able to run queries and get rows etc inside the code, and not first configure DataSet stuff

Comment: hence my advice to use any of the 3 methods listed, you'll find them much more user friendly, imho.